# is Simple GPS apps are allowed to use Car play framework?

Tags: ios, swift5, carplay

I want to create a new car play app for my existing iPhone app but as per apple guideline 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay
CarPlay framework mostly used for navigation, audio, VoIP calling and messaging apps but my app concept is not related to any one of these so I was confused will apple apple approve my app if I create my app that only use GPS for car location and can it be categorised under “Automaker apps” of car play.

So it will be very helpful if someone already did that and got approval for apple review team .

Below are the links for car play detail 
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/carplay/overview/automaker-apps/

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it took two weeks to get approved and the app I was working on strictly fell under the "audio" app category. Once I was approved there were some additional developer docs Apple provided (which helped lots).

From my research during the development of the audio app. It seemed Automaker apps were made from manufactures who Apple had partnered with.